# JSON Data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am creating an AngularJS client and connecting it to a REST API I have running on NodeJS. I do `GET` requests to get the data by going to the URL and then using the stock symbol i.e. `localhost:8080/stocks/aapl` for Apple's share data. In AngularJS I am using the `$http` service and then doing data-binding like this:

```
var restURL = "http://localhost:8080/stocks/" + searchSymbol;

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: restURL
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //Variables that are going to be used
    var data, symbol, companyName;
    //Parsing the data
    data = angular.fromJson(response);
    //Putting the data into the variables
    symbol = data.symbol;
    companyName = data.name;
    //Putting data from variables into Angular code
    $scope.companyName = companyName;
    $scope.symbol = symbol;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    var message = "Error getting response from server";
    $scope.errorMessage = message;
});
```

and this is what the view component looks like:

```html
<h1>Search Stocks</h1>
<p>Search for stocks using the text box below</p>

<p><input type="text" ng-model="searchSymbol" placeholder="Search by Symbol"></p>
<p><button ng-click="search()">Search</button></p>

<p> {{ symbol }}</p>
<p>{{ companyName }}</p>

<p>{{ errorMessage }}</p>
```

When I click the button, the `GET` request is reflected on the NodeJS server as it shows the company data in the terminal view however I can't seem to get it parsed in Angular.

Comment: Console out the value of data after this line: `data = angular.fromJson(response);`. What is the value of the object?

Comment: Debug on first line when you get back `response` and check what it is. Btw, you can just write `$http.get(restUrl).then(...`.

Comment: @SeanPerkins This is the result I get {data: {symbol: "AAPL", name: "Apple Inc.", price: 110.949997}, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: First glance looks like some issue with your searchSymbol ng-model. Not able to convert the data its getting from the node controller properly. Try out a  JS Fiddle and post that would be easier for ever to help you. With Angular controller and all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your response is an object which has a property data in it which contains symbol, your symbol assignment `symbol = data.symbol;` needs to change to `symbol = data.data.symbol;`
And likewise for companyName (use data.data.name).

See if that works.